# Finding focal point in XNA C# on lens physics

Tags: c#, xna, physics, game-physics

I was wondering if anyone has done any physics for XNA involving mirrors and lenses. Particularly how to find focal points, magnification ratios, image distance, and image heights?

Comment: Your question does not seem to be a programming question but rather a physical one. I assume that you already found the necessary formulas. What exactly do you need?

Comment: updating focal points dependent upon position of the object with a dynamic distance to a static lens. Or, a dynamic lens position with a static object.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_(optics) has all the information you need.
Only thing you need to define for your game is the focal length of the lens, the height of your object and its distance to the lens. This is a 99% physics and 1% programming question and does, in my opinion, not belong here.